# Рекурсивное удаление файлов через ftp положило сервер

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

Добрый день пытался удалить множество файлов через FileZilla Client, по итогу лег сервер. Почему это произошло? Это может произойти со всеми множественными операциями(скачивание, перемещение)?

Comment: Странно, что вопрос о сервере, но информации о сервере нет

Comment: @gil9red Как же нет :) Linux CentOs

Comment: подозреваю, что FileZilla  решила услужить и собрать информацию о кол-ве файлов, которые будут удалены и их размере.

Comment: Настройте сервер.

Comment: что значит положило...? сгорел винт, проц, сетевая не выдержала нагрузки... у нас десятки терабайт filezilla передает в течении 20ти лет ничего не падает :-)